# filtering, averaging and removing rows in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am in need of guidance.

Can you please direct me what library i can use for the following problem. I am fairly new with Python and I'm trying to do some statistics on some stock trading data. I apologize for not posting the example code as I literally don't know where to start.

The data I have is the following:

These are in total 3 trades which have been broken up into fragments and the goal is to combine them into 3 whole separate trades for further analyses.

Excess dates need to be removed as they are all the same, Time has to be averaged, excess Symbols have to be removed, Price needs to be averaged and quantity needs to be added. Route and Broker are not important

B = Buy, S = Sell, SS = Short Sell

```
          Date      Time  Symb Side    Price   Qty Route  Broker   
0   2017-12-05  12:26:13   VRX    B   2.2000  1000  PDQM     NaN    
1   2017-12-05  12:00:21   VRX   SS   2.1700   200  EDGE     NaN    
2   2017-12-05  12:00:21   VRX   SS   2.1700   100  EDGE     NaN   
3   2017-12-05  12:00:21   VRX   SS   2.1700   500  EDGE     NaN    
4   2017-12-05  12:00:21   VRX   SS   2.1700   200  EDGE     NaN  
5   2017-12-05  11:53:14   FRK    S   2.4000  1000  EDGE     NaN    
6   2017-12-05  11:52:41   FRK    B   2.4200   300  PDQM     NaN    
7   2017-12-05  11:52:41   FRK    B   2.4200   700  PDQM     NaN     
8   2017-12-05  11:51:53   CUR    B   2.3200  1000  PDQM     NaN    
9   2017-12-05  11:50:36   CUR   SS   2.1900   710  EDGE     NaN     
10  2017-12-05  11:50:32   CUR   SS   2.1900   290  SMAT     NaN
```

End result should look like this:

In total 3 trades, 6 lines as each trade consists of 2 sides, Buy and Sell, or Short Sale and Buy. Please note, data is backwards, from oldest trades at the bottom to the more recent ones in the top

```
          Date      Time  Symb Side    Price   Qty
0   2017-12-05  12:26:13   VRX    B   2.2000  1000 
1   2017-12-05  12:00:21   VRX   SS   2.1700  1000 
2   2017-12-05  11:53:14   FRK    S   2.4000  1000 
3   2017-12-05  11:52:41   FRK    B   2.4200  1000 
4   2017-12-05  11:51:53   CUR    B   2.3200  1000 
5   2017-12-05  11:50:34   CUR   SS   2.1900  1000
```

Comment: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
aggs = {"Price":"mean", "Qty":"sum","Time":"min"}

df = df.groupby(["Date","Symb", "Side"])[["Price","Qty","Time"]].agg(aggs)
df = df.reset_index()
```